# How to spin up variable number of instances in different regions in AWS using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

We are using Ansible with AWS for automatic provisioning of servers. I have a pretty clear understanding of how to use the ec2 module to bring up servers, but there are still some parts that are unclear.

My question is two-fold as follows:

1) How do I use ec2 to bring up for example 3 servers in region 1 and 5 servers in region 2, etc.. ? Do I use 2 separate playbooks, loop over the ec2 task, etc ? Basically if I want to bring up servers in multiple regions with different counts.

2) Once I have done step 1 above and created different numbers of servers in different regions, and use the add_host module to save their ips, how do I pass those ips on to the next steps in playbook, which would be multiple roles defined in separate files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The ips added using `add_host` can be used only in the same playbook.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Launch multiple instances in multiple regions
      ec2:
         ...
         region: "{{ item.region }}"
         count: "{{ item.count }}"
         ...
         assign_public_ip: yes
      register: ec2
      with_items:
        - { region: 'us-east-1', count: 2 }
        - { region: 'us-west-1', count: 5 }

    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=launched
      with_items: ec2.instances
```

Comment: This is perfect. Now, a follow up, can I put those regions into a variable file, and what should it look like ? Also, if I have subsequent roles I want to apply, should I just have one huge playbook, or can I include those roles in here and allow them to have acess to the hostnames that were just created ?